# Can two different HTML class elements be dragged and dropped in to one droppable area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am relatively new to JavaScript so this may seem like a dumb question. Is it possible to have multiple div elements with different id ors class names be dragged and dropped in to one droppable area? The examples I have seen online always define the droppable area to accept only one item of a specific class (or id) name.

In my use case I would like to have my droppable zone to accept to different items - one called .forms and the other called .pages and then take the appropriate action depending on which kind of element was dropped. Is this possible and how would one go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely possible. The relationships that you define between a draggable item and its drop target should be independent of any other draggables on your page (individual one-to-one relationships). You could then set up unique drop handlers (behavior) for each draggable item that you need.

Comment: Alternately, you could set up a system where you instantiate one 'Dropzone' object which has a `registerDraggable` method. This method could take—for example—a DOM element, a jQuery element, or a jQuery selector, as well as a callback function. Your Dropzone object would then set up an event listener that fires when that particular element was dropped, calling the associated callback function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I will give them a try.